# Passing props from one component to other component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass value `"red"` from `index.js` to `box.js` yet not working. Basically, I have a component that defines property of box and I want to pass background color "red" from `index.js` to `Box.js` component.

```js
// Box.js
import React from "react";
const box = {
  // here i would like to get the vlue name assign it to background
  background: this.props.name,
  width: "250px",
  height: "250px"
  // more code that defines how the box looks like here
};

export default Box;
```

```js
  /// index.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Box from "./Box";
  render() {
 

    return (
     // when calling Box, I would like to pass the value red to varivable name as shown below
    <Box name="red"></Box>
    )
   
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but in general you pass values to a component via `props`.

Comment: The question as written is unclear - can you clean up your code snippets to show what you're actually trying? Right now most of this code is invalid JS.

Comment: is your question is passing values from one component to another

Comment: correct i would like to pass the value red from main source code to box so that red will be assigned as background color

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a proper component:

```
// box.js
import React from "react";
const Box = (props) => {
  // here i would like to get the value name assign it to background
  const background = props.name;
  const width = "250px";
  const height = "250px";
  // more code that defines how the box looks like here
  return (
    // jsx code goes here
  );
};

export default Box;
```

in your second snippet, you are not using it properly

```
// index.js
import React from "react";
import Box from "./box"; // assuming that the file name is box.js and it is in the same folder

const BoxDisplay = (props) => {
    return (
       <Box name="red"/>
    );
};

export default BoxDisplay;
```

Or if you want an actual Component:

```
// index.js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Box from "./box";

export default class BoxDisplay extends Component({
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { //any initial state you want}
    }
    render() {
        return (<Box name="red"/>)
    }
});
```

Comment: box.js and index.js cannot be on the same file since box.js for two reasons. If i remove box.js some part of my code that depend on calling Box.js will fail. The second one is that I have to rewrite the same code everywhere i need box which makes the project unreasonably redundant

Comment: these are two different files - although you could combine them if you really wanted to - but I would recommend one file per component

Comment: not sure what you mean by rewriting the code - you just import box.js wherever you need it... code-reuse at its finest

Comment: got it but for some reason when i run it, it fails

Comment: can you be more specific? what fails?

Comment: i got Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined error

Comment: on box or index?

Comment: it is on index.js

Comment: Can you post your index.js?

Comment: pretty much same as posted above.

Comment: If you do not post the code, I cannot help... "pretty much the same as above" does not give any indication. On the contrary, it causes frustration. Good luck with your coding...

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in the question, please help us understand your problem in detail.

- Your default export name is "card " and you are trying to import
  "Box".
- what do you mean by main source code?
- Your index.js is not having a proper component syntax

please note that you cannot use "this.props" if you are not using a class based component or constructor rather use "props"

try changing the Box component as below:

```
const Box = (props) => {
    return <p style={{background: props.name}}> Content </p>
}
```